# Java System.load(libName) looks for wrong lib name

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I've run into a strange behaviour on one of our customers machine when trying to load a JNI library at runtime.

When trying to load a library with

```
System.load("libtestlibrary.so")
```

I get a

```
liblibtestlibrary.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems like the given library name is (wrongly) prefixed with "lib" and suffixed with ".so" and thus our library cannot be found.

This only happens on one machine (AIX 6). I was unable to reproduce this behaviour on our own AIX 6 box using the exact same JRE, so I'm guessing this is caused by some OS settings on the customer machine.

Does anybody have an idea how to turn this off?

Comment: Try either `System.load("/fullpath/libtestlibrary.so")` or `System.loadLibrary("testlibrary")`. The latter combined with setting property `java.library.path` accordingly.

Comment: A note: use utility `truss(1)` to debug, with option `-f`

Comment: The problem is not the path, the library is found in the current directory. The problem is the modification of the library name by prefixing it with "lib" and suffixing it with ".so". I understand that I could load the library by using `System.load("testlibrary")`, but in this case the code will fail on all other platforms. `System.loadLibrary("testlibrary")` should be used for native libraries as far as I understand the documantation.

Comment: Some notes: 1. in Unix, current directory rarely or never used when searching for shared libraries; it's `LIBPATH` (and `java.library.path`when using Java) that defines the directories to search. 2. with no method can 'non-native libraries' be loaded (eg 32-bit shared objects when using 64-bit Java or vice versa). 3. The error message you get might be bogus, if interested what is really happening, use gdb or truss. Also please read my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
System.loadLibrary("libraryname");
```

It will be properly expanded to system specific notation. Or you can use:

```
System.load("you_can_have_anything_you_like_here")
```

In second case, all you need to do is to point to proper location of file. If you are looking for cross system development, you might be interested in packaging your native code inside JAR. Take a look here for a sample code where library is taken from JAR file

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031

Also, make sure that other libraries are available in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Note that `java.library.path` is only valid for your "first" native lib. If your code uses some other shared libs, you have to either compile with rpath or make sure libraries are visible system wide.

Yet another approach is to go via stub: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/

In that case, you can load library as you like and do whatever you like (e.g. change native code on the fly).